# Attach multiple query tabs in BigQuery to the same BQ Session

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I cannot find a way to do this in the UI: I'd like to have distinct query tabs in the BigQuery's UI attached to the same session (i.e. so they share the same `@@session_id` and `_SESSION` variables). For example, I'd like to create a temporary table (session-scoped) in one tab, then in a separate query tab be able to refer to that temp table.

As far as I can tell, when I put a query tab in Session Mode, it *always* creates a new session, which is precisely what I don't want :-\

Is this doable in BQ's UI?

Answer (score 0):

There is 3rd party IDE for BigQuery supporting such a feature (*namely: joining Tab(s) into existing session*)

This is Goliath - part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).

Let's see how it works there:

- Step 1 - create Tab with new session and run some query to actually initiate session

[image]

- Step 2 - create new Tab(s) and join to existing session (either using session_id or just simply respective Tab Name

[image]

So, now both Tabs(Tab 2 and Tab 3) share same session with all expected perks
You can add as many Tabs to that session as you want to comfortably organize your workspace

[image]

And, as you can see Tabs that belong to same session are colored in user defined color so easy to navigate between them

***Note**: Another tool in this suite is Magnus - Workflow Automator. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc. Supports GitHub as a source control as well*

***Disclosure**: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team*